# How do I target Pixel 3a in React Native to fix the front camera that blocks hamburger menu icon?

Tags: react-native

The Pixel 3a put the front camera inside the viewable screen and it's blocking the hamburger menu icon. Is there a way to target this device?

Comment: I guess you could just take screenwidth and screenheight and style accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> react-native-safe-area-context provides a flexible API for accessing device safe area inset information. This allows you to position your content appropriately around notches, status bars, home indicators, and other such device and operating system interface elements. It also provides a SafeAreaView component that you can use in place of View to automatically inset your views to account for safe areas.

SafeAreaContext should do the trick. If you are using expo [check out the official docs for more info.](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/safe-area-context/)

If not, [try out this library.](https://github.com/th3rdwave/react-native-safe-area-context)

Comment: Glad to help :) Could you please accept my answer as the correct one? Trying to get some rep... Cheers!